# No module named 'ffnet' in Python

Tags: python, installation

I try a python code for signature recognition, and there is an import ffnet module (`from ffnet import mlgraph, ffnet`), but I got an error when I run it.

The error is:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ffnet'`

I have install the module, but still got that error

Help me to fix this :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that it is correctly installed. The error message means directly "You haven't installed it properly". 
Depending on what Python version you're using, you should have a package manager called `pip` that takes charge of installing and uninstalling modules. Try:

- `pip2 install ffnet` if you have Python 2.
- `pip3 install ffnet` if you have Python 3.

Alternatively, you may have installed Python using Anaconda. In this case, use `conda install ffnet`. In all cases, run the proposed commands in a terminal. 
However, it would be quite useful to have more details about your problem (what OS do you have, how and where did you install Python, what version do you have).

Answer (score 0):

There is great chance that the `pip` (i suppose you use pip for installation, the idea is identical) you use to install ffnet is not correspond to the `python` you are using. Maybe a virtualenv is running, or you using python 2 but ffnet is installed with pip3
My suggestion:
 - Run `which pip`. Run `which python`. Compare the results if anything seem wrong (python2 pip3 for example). Try to run `python2` and `pip2` instead of `python` and `pip`
 - If the above suggestion doesn't work, you should try to recheck your PATH: Find the `pip` correspond to your current python (usually within the same dir) and `export PATH=/path/to/THAT/pip/:$PATH`
 - If the problem still persist, I suppose your `pip` file's first line (for specifying its corresponding `python` path) has been modified without your awareness. You will have to manually edit it to something like `#!/usr/bin/python3`

Hope this help!